# US: How do offshore bank accounts help?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, capital-gains-tax, international-transfer

How does having an offshore bank account help? From my (limited) understanding, the U.S. taxes on all income worldwide, so placing money offshore would still be taxed normally.

Why, then, do high net worth individuals open offshore bank accounts (ex. Panama Papers, etc)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Super basic/unrealistic example but:

Let's say you run a hedge fund in New York. You make 50% a year in investing profit and don't want to pay tax.

Well you're a hedge fund so you might argue you want to make sure you *preserve* capital at all costs. You therefore might want to insure a large portion of your profit each year in case the market swings against you. Insurance costs money so now a huge chunk of your profit is getting sent as a cost of business to a specialist financial asset insurance company.

You incidentally also open and own this insurance company and are basically its only customer. It's also based in the Cayman's with it's very low (zero) corporate tax rate. So now you have a thriving, low tax insurance business charging huge margins to its one customer and quickly sucking your profits off shore out of your NY hedge fund.

Insurance companies also do a thriving business investing all these premiums they get to make even more than just their insurance margin. Well, you know of at least one excellent investment for you new insurance revenue: a thriving hedge fund in New York. The insurance company can now thus invest into your fund, complete the loop and swelling its assets while avoiding certain types of potential tax, or sit on it for however long you want to pass to your kids, invest it elsewhere etc etc.

All of these processes require bank accounts to move the money around and sit on the cash etc.

This is a toy example and the reality is a lot more complex and shifting as certain loopholes appear and are closed but is a super basic flow for the style of setup of how offshoring and off shore bank accounts can help people and companies avoid tax.

Comment: This is extremely insightful. I'm rather new to tax as a whole. Would you (the hedge fund) not get taxed on the money before it's sent off to the insurance company? If the insurance company invests in the hedge fund again, wouldn't that just return the tax rate of the company back to normal?

Comment: The way this is being set up the insurance cost is just a standard business expense in your pursuit of capital preservation, in the same way as you can deduct any other cost from your final profit tax (staff, R&D etc).

Comment: I see. Would this then be similar to how Amazon is able to deduct tax expenses by buying back their own shares? (I'm *extremely* new to studying taxation, so if this is a basic question, please bear with me)

Comment: Amazon is much better known for ploughing virtually all of its profits back into R&D to try and grow new businesses (eg it makes a million in one year but invests all that million into buying things to expand the store thus making no profit, so that next year it now makes two million from this expansion which it then spends on further expansion and so on). Buy backs get more complex as few more moving parts/considerations but good overview here to get started: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Share_repurchase

Comment: This is the key missing from other answers. As an American individual, yes your income is taxed worldwide. However what is considered 'income' to you personally may be different than just 'what all of your investments earn', and especially the use of intervening corporate layers may delay / defer that income recognition for many years. It is the *combination* of multiple complex tax rules that creates what you and I would call 'loopholes'.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon so what, then, stops me from making a corporation that all my wages are paid to, where the corporation takes care of my every expense, and "investing" all the money back into buying other stocks and R&D and whatnot? Would this not be a legitimate tax loophole in that would result in no tax paid?

Comment: The key part here is 'taking care of your every expense'. Want to setup a complex tax structure to shuffle your money around corporate entities like warehouses, new machinery, insurance/futures contracts etc and never pay tax on your huge and growing business? That's fairly simple. Setting up one that can buy you food, champagne and Lambos directly in NY etc is basically impossible as they are not legitimate business expenses and the money for them has to be paid to you at some point as some form of income or capital gain, at which point it becomes a little easier to tax.

Comment: @user760900 What stops you is basically the intricacies of the tax laws themselves. What 'works' and what 'doesnt work' is based on very specific interactions of very specifically worded legal writing. This answer gives a great answer that is as simplistic as it needs to be to get the point across, but of course it is no where near complete enough to actually show a 'step by step' instruction. In many cases that level of detail would be literally hundreds of thousands of dollars in legal bills. These are not simple issues, which is why they are hard to convey to lay people.

Answer (score 5):

One reason an offshore account is used is to hide income from the tax authority. Then when the person completes their tax forms they neglect to report the income. They never report the bank balance. Thus they commit tax fraud.

Another reason to do it is if the income itself was illegal, or they want to hide a significant portion of their wealth from creditors or from their soon to be ex-spouse. That can also be considered fraud.

Now some people do have non-US accounts, and do report the income and the bank balance. They have legitimate reasons for having the account, and they don't cheat on their taxes.

Comment: assuming no tax fraud, would it be useless to place money offshore?

Comment: @user760900 - nowadays, utterly, totally, completely useless. It's just not a thing anymore. (For US citizens.)

Comment: @Fattie Not true at all. It's very convenient to have money in an account in the country where you will spend it.

Answer (score 1):

There are no financial benefits, and there are reporting hassles.  The only legitimate reason for a foreign bank account is if you operate in that country routinely and want a local bank account.

Comment: Would you then refute Philip's answer?

Comment: @user760900 Note that I said "legitimate".  He's describing questionable tax games.

Comment: questionable as in illegal? I fail to see how it would be questionable if legal

Comment: @user760900 Income is supposed to be reported where it's earned.  What he's describing is likely tax evasion.